# Drawing outside of the QPaintEvent handler

Tags: c++, qt

We have big QT project where painting procedure often doesn't follow the rule that it should be done in overridden **paintEvent** method. As result we have warnings about it: Painter not active etc... But all work fine and at first glance I don't see any problems. Could you explain should I worry about it or not? What is the price of the incorrect use of this functionality?

Comment: Could you be more specific. I believe painters can be used outside of `paintEvent` functions, so "painter is not active" message can be caused by something else.

Comment: Cannot agree. Simple example. If you look on QPainter::setFont method you could see that in this case wanted font will not be set:

    if (!d->engine) {
        qWarning("QPainter::setFont: Painter not active");
        return;
}

Comment: Well, but how it relates to `paintEvent` function?

Comment: Since you mention `paintEvent` I'm assuming the `QPaintDevice` in question is (or derives from) `QWidget`?  If that's the case then I don't think painting outside `paintEvent` is generally supported (although I can't find a definitive statement to that effect).  Having said that, I've been using `Qt` for longer than I care to remember/admit and have never needed to paint to a widget outside of the `paintEvent` method.

Answer (score 0):

Paint event is sended to the window when it is should be updated, eg when it is shown or something else. For example if widget is covered by another window, and this windows is moved away, then widget should be updated. Common way is to paint on the pixmap and draw this pixmap on the widget in the paint event handler. Or you can update/repaint each time you need to repaint it.

You can use QPainter to draw on pixmap, printer and so on whenever you want, but to draw on windget it must be done in paintEvent.

Comment: It seems it is my situation. I prepare pixmaps to draw on widget later.

Comment: @Mikola in this case you should not receive warnings. Check again maybe some where you try to paint on widget instead of pixmap?

Comment: Yes it confuses me - I have such warnings.... I will investigate. But any case can I make conclusion that in case of wrong using the corresponding functionality will not work(brush, font, pen etc...)?

Comment: @Mikola which version of Qt you are using? In my case of incorrect usage of QPainter I get QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Comment: For different devices I have few QT versions - starting from 4.6 to 5.9.

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake - it is happened when invalid pixmap(I have created pixmap with size 0x0) is used. I have add check on it and now all are okey.